# Need help parsing Google Maps Timeline data using javascript/json

Tags: javascript, json, nested-object

I am kinda new to Javascript, and I was hoping to parse through Google Maps' Timeline Data.  My goal is to essentially pull out only key data, such as location address, miles, etc from each location I travelled to each year.  I am finding myself getting stuck on what I thought would be the easy part of the task, looping through tons of nested arrays and objects.  Maybe I bit off more than I can chew on this one, but it will help with my taxes this April.

The structure of the original is much more complex, but the gist of it is that there are two objects per location in the data:  activitySegment and placeVisit.  In those objects, there are a bunch more objects.  How would I go about accessing the deeply nested objects to pull out key pieces of info?  I am new to looping, and am looking for any advice possible to aid me.

```
{
  "timelineObjects" : [ {
    "activitySegment" : {
      "startLocation" : {"latitudeE7" : 376307753,"longitudeE7" : -1220965320 }
    }
    "placeVisit" : {
      "location": {
        "address": SOME ADDRESS
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Thanks! this helped get me passed some things that I was struggling with